# Passing SQL Data to another activity Android Studio

Tags: android

Having some issues working out how to pass my SQL Data to another activity when I tap on an entry. For example entering the values of the data base into a Edit Text box so its auto filled. Is there a way that you can do that in Android Studio?

Comment: Simply pass the search arguments to the new Activity. There you will query the database helper class with those parameters.

Comment: The thing is that I don't know where to get the data from? From the Cursor or  from somewhere else.

Comment: Then you should follow some tutorial on android database management.

Comment: Cool thanks for the tip